# My login_form hides as I go to user_form, and vice-versa. But after that when I close login pannel it still runs in background

Tags: c#, winforms

First button takes us to user form and second button brings us back to login form.

But if login form is closed after once logging in, it stays in background but if no one clicks login and just closes the login form, then it closes just fine.

It also stays in background if I close user form directly. I also tried `this.Close();` command but if I do that the current form closes and the other form doesn't open at all.

```
private void User_login_b_Click(object sender, Event Args e)
{
    this.Hide();
    User user = new User();
    user.Show();
}


private void Logout_b_Click(object sender, Event Args e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Login login = new Login();
    login.Show();
}
```

Comment: Please do not tag spam. 1) It seems unlikely that you're developing your application with both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. 2) The tool you're using to author your code is inconsequential to the running of your code. 3) This is not a question about WinForms designer. Your question is about WinForms APIs.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Logout_b_Click* event handler you are creating a new instance of the Login form while the first instance still exists. You need to use the Application.OpenForms collection to find the existant instance and show it again

```
private void Logout_b_Click(object sender, Event Args e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Login login = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Login>();
    if(login == null) 
         login = new Login();
    login.Show();
}
```